# How do I get the HTML body from a URL using Nokogiri in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I want to parse the body attributes from a URL.

For example:

```
url = 'http://rca.yandex.com/?key=rca.1.1.20140120T051507Z.3db118ab435efdff.6c84331313b6b7d66abd191410f72e0e1c3c8795&url=http://endtimeheadlines.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/think-tank-extraordinary-crisis-needed-to-preserve-new-world-order/#comment-36708?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=facebook[&callback=http://64.191.99.245:3023/posts][&full=1]'
```

When I try:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

I get:

```
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x52fd6d6 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x52fd1f4 name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x52fc6aa name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5301f56 name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x53018d0 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x53015f6 "http://rca.yandex.com/?key=rca.1.1.20140120T051507Z.3db118ab435efdff.6c84331313b6b7d66abd191410f72e0e1c3c8795&url=http://endtimeheadlines.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/think-tank-extraordinary-crisis-needed-to-preserve-new-world-order/#comment-36708?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=facebook[&callback=http://64.191.99.245:3023/posts][&full=1]">]>]>]>]>
```

How do I get the attributes inside this URL?

For example: `page.css("div")`. I want to get the value from HTML `body`.

Comment: I'd recommend reading through the ["Searching" tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) provided for Nokogiri. It's plenty adequate for explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, define "attributes"? Attributes of the body tag would normally be any things like `on_load`. Do you mean child-nodes or inner-HTML?

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 24):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but this might help:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<html><head><title>foo</title><body><p>bar</p></body></html>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

Using [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at), you'll find the first occurrence of the tag, which is sensible in a HTML document since you should only have a single `<body>` tag.

```
doc.at('body') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff194d24cd4 name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff194d24acc name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff194d248c4 "bar">]>]>
```

If you want the children of the tag, use `children` to retrieve them:

```
doc.at('body').children # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff194d24acc name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff194d248c4 "bar">]>]
```

If you want to get the child nodes as HTML:

```
doc.at('body').children.to_html # => "<p>bar</p>"
doc.at('body').inner_html # => "<p>bar</p>"
```

If you want the text content of the body tag:

```
doc.at('body').content # => "bar"
doc.at('body').text # => "bar"
```

If, by "attributes", you really mean the [`attributes`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attributes) of the `<body>` tag itself:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<html><head><title>foo</title><body on_load="do_something()"><p>bar</p></body></html>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('body').attributes # => {"on_load"=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdc3d923ca0 name="on_load" value="do_something()">}
doc.at('body')['on_load'] # => "do_something()"
```

[`attributes`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attributes) returns a hash, so you can directly access anything you want. As a shortcut, a Nokogiri::XML::Node also understands [`[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D) giving us a typical Hash-style access to the value.

Answer (score 3):

`page.css('body')` should work. If not try using `to_s`

Comment: Don't use `to_s` as the result will be a string representation of the contents of the body tag, which wouldn't be very useful. Also, `css` doesn't return what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_xml` or `to_html` or other formats as required.  Please reference [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/) documentation for other formatting options.

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
page.to_xml
```

And to get the body of the `div` in your `document`, use:

```
divs = page.css('div') # returns either string or array depending upon the number of divs in your document.
divs.to_xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course you get the parsed *HTML/XML* tree which has been got from the link. And hither is in thine example:

```
page.css("div")
```

thou just tryst to get all of the `div`s in the parsed document as an `Array`. Thou canst enumerate them one-by-one, and getst the text of each of the `div`:

```
page.css("div").each do| div |
   p div.text
end
```

Comment: While it might seem fun to write in pseudo-Shakespearean English, remember, you're writing answers being read by many people who do not speak English as their primary language. Stack Overflow endeavors to be like the Wikipedia of programming questions, so please stick to easily read, standard English to the best of your ability.